# Convert function inside a service into observable in angular

Tags: angular, http, service, observable

I have a function called **setRefreshedWebToken** inside a service file which sends an HTTP get request and get values from the DB.
Then it will do some tasks using the data obtained from the request.

```
   private setRefreshedWebToken(duration: number) 
    {  this.refreshTokenTimer = setTimeout(() => {
              this.http
                .get<{
                  token: string;
                  expiration: number;
                }>("http://localhost:3000/api/v1/token")
                .subscribe(
                  (response) => 
                  {             //some task             },
                  (error) => {
                    //console log the error
                  }
                );
            }, duration);  }
```

How ever, this method is called inside another method called **autoAuthUser**.

```
autoAuthUser() 
{
 this.setRefreshedWebToken(1000);

 //rest of the code

}
```

But I want to run the rest of the code ( //rest of the code ) once **setRefreshedWebToken** function is finished.
 Rest of the code has to wait till **setRefreshedWebToken** method is finished.
 As far as I know, **setrefreshedWebToken** method involves asynchronous code due to the get request. I think observable is the way to overcome my problem.
 I want to have something like below.

```
private setRefreshedWebToken(duration: number) : Observable<boolean> 
     {
        //how to handle this
     }


      autoAuthUser()  {
                   this.setRefreshedWebToken(1000).subscribe
((x)=>  {  //rest of the code  }  );     
                 }
```

Since I am new to Angular, I have no clear idea whether I am doing this correct as HTTP request is also observable and I am also trying to create an observable based on that. I want to avoid memory leaks as well. 
 I have no idea on how to transform **setRefreshedWebToken** method to work as observable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason why you using timeout? When you can just return the `http.get` which is already `Observable` then you can do what you wanted with `subscribe`

Comment: These functions are related to web token replacement. I am using a timeout to handle a task related to that.